# Function and function-pointer equivalence

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I have two classes; class A notifies class B about some events.

```
typedef void (*callbackb) (B *, int param1);

class A
{
  callbackb callme;
  B *parent;
};

class B
{
  A ai;
  void set_cb() { ai.callme = cb_handler; }
  static void cb_handler (B *obj, int param1) { obj->real_handler(param1); }
  void real_handler(int param1);
};
```

There are two equivalent declarations, callbackb and cb_handler, but one of them is a function pointer, and other one is a function. Is it possible to change one or both, so that both were linked to single prototype declaration?

Comment: This is somewhat of an antipattern. If `class A` should be strictly tied to `class B`, the proper type for `callbackb` is `void (B::*)(int param)` - a pointer to member. This eliminates the pointless `cb_handler`. But if `class A` should not be tied strictly, the proper type would be `std::function<void(int)>`, and you'd use a lambda or bind in `B::set_cb` to capture `this`.

Comment: @MSalters, I can't use C++11 capabilities due to platform limitations, but this could be an interesting example, if you would wish to expand your comment into answer.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the question you posed TBH. As for C++11, `std::function` is a formalization of `boost::function`. The latter was implemented in C++03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't **define** `cb_handler` like you want. But you certainly can declare them based off the same prototype and have the compiler check it. It also stops you from hiding pointer semantics, which is a good thing. Here's how:

1. Define the callback as a **function type**:

   ```
   typedef void callbackb(B *, int param1);
   ```
2. Declare the pointer and static member in terms of the CB type:

   ```
   class A
   {
     callbackb *callme; // The pointer is explicit
     B *parent;
   };

   // Later
   class B
   {
     // ...
     static inline callbackb cb_handler; // This is a function declaration
   };
   // And this is the inline definition, you can put it in a header
   inline void B::cb_handler (B *obj, int param1) { obj->real_handler(param1); }
   ```

So now `cb_handler` and `callme` are declared in terms of the same type. You need to specify the complete prototype when *defining* `cb_handler`, but it can still be an `inline` out-of-class definition in a header.

The compiler will check that the definition of `cb_handler` matches the declaration, so you'll be notified if `cb_handler` differs from `callbackb`.